# SOCIALENGINE: get gender of the user

Tags: socialengine

SocialEngine4: How can I get the gender of the user using sql query?

Answer (score 2):

```
$subject = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject(); //Get user

$fields = $subject->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias();
$gender = $fields['gender'];

$this->view->gender = $gender;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this listed below code:

```
<?php
$currentUserID=Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();
$sSqlInviter="select gender from engine4_user_fields_search where item_id=".$currentUserID;
$dbInviterSqli=Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$stmtInviter=$dbInviterSqli->query($sSqlInviter);
$rowInviter=$stmtInviter->fetch();
$gender=$rowInviter['gender'];
if($gender==2) 
  echo "<b> Male</b>";
else
  echo "<b> Female</b>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
$fields = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer);
echo $fields['gender'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using default profile question? Then:

```
From engine4_ser_fields_option
```

There is  and option id for the particular field.